# Function rewriting different responses in Atom vs. Chrome console?

Tags: javascript, function, url-rewriting, console, atom-editor

I placed this bit of code in both atom and the chrome console.

```js
function a() {
  alert('A');
  return function() {
    alert('B');
  };
}
a = a();
```

In the chrome console it works likes its supposed to, the first time it is run it shows A the second time it is run it shows B. However, in the case of using Atom each run shows A and it never switches to b? Why is this?

Comment: Atom is starting a new Javascript session every time you run it.

Comment: It's like opening a new console in Chrome each time.

Comment: How do you run JavaScript files in Atom ?

Comment: That was useful: https://discuss.atom.io/t/how-do-i-build-or-execute-code-ive-written-in-atom/25341